# SQLCMD - SQL Server Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

suppose below is my query.

```
DECLARE @INT INT
SET @INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable)
IF (@INT = 0)
RAISERROR('Fail',16,1)
```

I want to use this query and create a SQL Server job using "Operating System (CmdExec)" type.
I want to SQL Job step to be successful if @INT <> 0 and fail if @INT = 0.

How can I write the cmd?

My try (and it doesn't work)...the server is different than where I will be setting up the job.

```
sqlcmd -S 123.45.67.890 -E -V15 -d MyDB -Q "DECLARE @INT INT
SET @INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable)
IF (@INT = 0)
RAISERROR('Fail',16,1)" -b
```

Job failure msg.

Executed as user: LocalSVR\USER. Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server RemoteSVR, Line 1  Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'DECLARE @INT INT '.  Process Exit Code 15.  The step failed.

Please note, the step fails for the same reason when MyTable has 1+ record(s).

Update: As per Scott's suggestion, I changed the formatting (removed line breaks) and it seems to work. @Scott, not sure how to mark your comment as answer. If you can write a response, I will mark it as answer. Cheers!!!

Comment: Is that exactly how it's formatted in your job? Sqlcmd probably doesn't like having your query spanning multiple lines. If you remove the line breaks it might work.

Comment: Umm...wow!! think this was it..lol Thanks @ScottTeibert for this tip. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute multiple lines as opposed to a single query. You can get round that by using IF NOT EXISTS

```
SQLCMD -b -S"MyServer" -d"MyDatabase" -Q"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable) RAISERROR('Fail',16,1)"
```

Note that the -b (On error batch abort) option means that SQLCMD itself will fail giving you a Trappable ErrorLevel